# How do I create a string if I know characters at each index (in c++)

Tags: c++, string

I tried printing the string I created, but it doesn't exist. As you can see, the output shows length is 0:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string a="";
  a[0]='a';
  a[1]='b';
  a[2]='c';

  cout<<"length of a: "<< a.length();
}
```

Output to the console is:

> length of a: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code has undefined behavior because you access elements out of bounds. The string has `size()` (which is the same as `length()`) `0` so `a[0]` and the others access elements that don't exist.

To make it work, you must `resize()` the string first.

Example:

```
string a;
a.resize(3);
a[0]='a';
a[1]='b';
a[2]='c';
```

You can also create the string with the proper length directly:

```
string a(3, '\0'); // create a string of length 3 filled with \0 chars
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I got it !

Answer (score 1):

1)This `string a="";` length of character here is 0 so it size also 0.

2)

```
a[0]='a';
a[1]='b';
a[2]='c';
```

it undefined behavior You are accessing out of bounds

3)so Add `a.resize(3);` to your code that is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string a="";
a.resize(3);  // this will resize 
a[0]='a';
a[1]='b';
a[2]='c';
cout<<"length of a: "<< a.length();
}
```

Or `string a="xxx"`;  fill some characters initially or use `push_back();` like

```
a.push_back('a');
a.push_back('b');
a.push_back('c');
```

Comment: @Ajay Tyagi B18ME003    if you got the answer feel free accept any one of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to acces an element whhich hasn't existed yet.
`a` is an empty string so has size of `0`, hence `a[0]`  is undefined behavior because the size at least should be `1`.

To avoid that use `resize()` before assigning to `a`, as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string a="";
a.resize(3);
a[0]='a';
a[1]='b';
a[2]='c';

cout<<"length of a: "<< a.length();
}
```

Or use `push_back`, as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string a="";
a.push_back('a');
a.push_back('b');
a.push_back('c');

cout<<"length of a: "<< a.length();
}
```

The first solution is better than the second to avoid reallocating.

Also see this [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably build a `char` array, and then you can use the [from sequence](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) string constructor.